# Reverse-engineer Cubase .cpr format

Tags: audio, reverse-engineering, audacity

I don't have an opportunity to buy Cubase, but my partner uses it a lot. I wanted to simplify his life and provide him with cpr projects instead of plain wav files, but no other software can open/save this format.

I looked at a sample cpr he sent me and it seems like the file does not contain audio data itself, it rather contains the mark-up and effects.

I wanted to know the following things:

1. Is it legal to try to reverse-engineer cpr files?
2. Is it difficult and who tried?
3. If someone knows other ways to transfer project files between Audacity/Rosegarden and Cubase? The main thing is the support of several tracks and their timing in one project, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cpr files comes from a proprietary format. You can have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121208/is-it-legal-to-reverse-engineer-binary-file-formats).
2. I suppose it is pretty hard... and I didn't tried !
3. To my knowledge, there is no way to export/import a project between cubase and Audacity or Rosegarden. The OMF format which could be a good candidate, is not supported by Audacity or Rosegarden for now. You can still import/export the audio mix, the separated tracks, and the midi files separately. This method is really fastidious, but it probably provides the advantage to let you play and edit your projects in the next decades, that isn't obvious with project files.